# Authenticate Phonegap app against Windows Azure AD while accessing data from Web API

Tags: azure, cordova, acs

We have a phonegap mobile application created using JQuery Mobile and HTML5. This application fetches data from server using Web API. User had to authenticate against AD to use this application.
Now we want to integrate windows azure ACS/AD and authenticate users using OAuth2.
Can anyone point us into right direction?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it myself. If anyone is having similar issue, let me know.

Comment: Could you provide some links to the solution you chose?

Comment: I used this resource http://chrisrisner.com/Accessing-Resources-Secured-by-Azure-Active-Directory-with-iOS-and-Android and modified it to adapt my application. Let me know if this is helpful for you.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I'm having the same problem